# Encrypt with Crypto.JS and decrypt with PHP 7.3

Tags: php, encryption

I'm upgrading my code from PHP 5.6 to 7.3 which is a Woocommerce Plugin for my Ionic app. In the meantime I noted that mcrypt_decrypt is deprecated in PHP 7. I tried to figured out how to change my code, but it still does not return the same string. Here is my encryption code in the app:

```
var password = this.password;
if (this.appConfig.App_Secret != '') {
  var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.MD5(this.appConfig.App_Secret).toString());
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.MD5(this.appConfig.App_Secret).toString().substr(0, 16));
  password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, key, { iv: iv }).toString();
}
```

And this is my old decryption code in PHP:

```
$iv=substr(md5(get_option('sow_rest_api_secret')),0,16);
$key = md5(get_option('sow_rest_api_secret'));
$data = base64_decode($decrypt_str);
$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
return rtrim($result,"\0");
```

I change the line with the $result variable from

```
$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

to

```
$result = openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-128-gcm', $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

Can you give support?

Comment: If `rtrim($result,"\0")` is used to remove Zero padding, this would not be necessary since both CryptoJS and `openssl_decrypt` use PKCS7 padding by default and un-padding is implicitly done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [this php.net comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667):

> Also, MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES-256, it's a different variant of the Rijndael block cipher. **If you want AES-256 in mcrypt, you have to use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 with a 32-byte key.** OpenSSL makes it more obvious which mode you are using (i.e. 'aes-128-cbc' vs 'aes-256-ctr').

This means that you've been using AES-256 before, and not AES-128.

Furthermore, CryptoJS uses CBC mode by default, as correctly noted by @Topaco.

Putting this together:

```
$result = openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

should give the same result, as your previous `mcrypt_decrypt` solution.

Comment: _CryptoJS_ uses the CBC mode by default, i.e. for a successful decryption `aes-256-cbc` is required as algorithm/mode (which is why `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` was specified in the deprecated code).